# OS X Yosemite Download Upgrade Install Later

Tags: macos, download, installation

Why is the OS X upgrader so bad?

Once the OS X Yosemite upgrade is downloaded, if you restart the machine you have to download the whole thing again, in order to get the "Continue installation of OS X Yosemite ..." window to come back up.

Is there a way to install on a separate occasion to downloading? This is seriously frustrating because i just restarted since i couldn't get the window to appear, only to notice the window was hidden behind "App Store" once reboot was already initiated. After restart however it is not possible to get the upgrade window back.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems unclear.

After you finish your download of osx 10.10 and start the restarting process the downloaded file is installed not redownloaded. From the sounds of it you have already updated to 10.10 and if that is the case you can not get the update window back.

If you are having a lot of issues with your download, you can reinstall the entire os through internet recovery by turning off your laptop, holding command R and turning it back on

good luck